# git push with different user than current unix user

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a new repo with git.  The server is https.  I'm logged in as another user which isn't authorized to push into the server. Can I push with a specific username?  I do the following:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git.example.com/repo/project.git
git config auth
git config credential.https://git.example.com/repo/project.git username@example.com
git push -v origin master
```

For example I get asked to login as vagrant, not username@example.com:

```
vagrant@lucid64:~/django_projects$ git push origin master
vagrant@git.frogdesign.com's password:
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If so, please post an answer and mark it as the accepted answer, it will help others in the future :)

Answer (score 4):

Try: `git remote set-url origin ssh://user@git.example.com/repo/project.git`

Comment: i added that line after i added the origin.  my passwords doesn't work at the prompt though.  any reason why?  when i change ssh to https the password works but i get : error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0

Answer (score 1):

There is a small wrong in your `git config credential.https...`.

It should be :

```
git config credential.https://github.com/repo/project\.git.username [YOUR_EMAIL]
```

**Should be ' project\.git ',  not ' project.git '.**

**Do not forget the ' \ ',  escape character.**

---

You can `less .git/config` to check it out:

```
[credential "https://github.com/repo/project.git"]
    username = [YOUR_EMAIL]
```

---

`git config` is **doing the same job** as `vim .git/config`.

`git config --global` is **doing the same job** as `vim ~/.gitconfig`

---

You can `man git-config` and `man gitcredentials` for more information.